# How can I display a buddypress group name in the header.php so that it shows when viewing each single group?

Tags: buddypress

I tried the code below but it doesn't do anything when place in the buddypress default header.php file. Ideally I'd like to have the group name display to the right of the logo in the bp default theme when visiting each group. Thanks for any help.

```
<?php bp_group_name(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this one myself. Just used the following code:

```
 <?php bp_current_group_name() ?>
```